# jQuery click function on wrong selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, click, jquery-events

I have a problem with a selector.

Actually I'm writing a widget.

There have to be 2 click events to change an class.
The problem is, that if I click the first event, the class will change. But on the second click, it always goes to the same click event, even though it has the wrong class (selector)

```
            $(".ui-multiselect-costum-button",$(this)).click(function(){
                console.log($(this).parent().html());
                console.log($(this).attr("class"));
                $(this).removeClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button").addClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button-active");
                console.log($(this).attr("class"));
                console.log($(this).parent().html());
            });

            $(".ui-multiselect-costum-button-active",$(this)).click(function(){

                console.log($(this).attr("class"));
                $(this).removeClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button-active").addClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button");
                console.log($(this).attr("class"));
            });
```

the console show this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-multiselect-costum-button"></span>
 ui-multiselect-costum-button
 ui-multiselect-costum-button-active
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-multiselect-costum-button-active"></span>

 <input type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-multiselect-costum-button-active"></span>
 ui-multiselect-costum-button-active
 ui-multiselect-costum-button-active
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-multiselect-costum-button-active"></span>
```

So why does the click event always uses ui-multiselect-costum-button and not ui-multiselect-costum-button-active?

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the handlers to the elements that have the classes at the time you initialize the plugin. You need to use event delegation so that it will follow the dynamic class changes:

```
        $(this).on("click", ".ui-multiselect-costum-button", function(){
            console.log($(this).parent().html());
            console.log($(this).attr("class"));
            $(this).removeClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button").addClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button-active");
            console.log($(this).attr("class"));
            console.log($(this).parent().html());
        });

        $(this).on("click", ".ui-multiselect-costum-button-active", function(){
            console.log($(this).attr("class"));
            $(this).removeClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button-active").addClass("ui-multiselect-costum-button");
            console.log($(this).attr("class"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When init jquery and assign a click event to both class, will bind in same time, means:

assign click event to `$(".ui-multiselect-costum-button",$(this))`,

after that assing click event to `(".ui-multiselect-costum-button-active",$(this))` which doesn't exists until you must click on first class `$(".ui-multiselect-costum-button",$(this))` (there in that function will change class name to -active) but click event for new class name doesn't exists.

So you have to assing again click to new class. Follow Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on instead of click. Your events are getting bind to the elements on document load to the corresponding elements. You are changing the class of the element in the event, but the events were already bind to those elements on document load, the events are not bind again on change of class as you are using click.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Event delegation worked :D

My oppinio was, that 'on' an 'click' did the same.